# Capture standard output from CreateProcessAsUser in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, createprocessasuser

I'm currently starting processes within an asp.net website using the pinvoke CreateProcessAsUser api.  This works perfectly to impersonate the logged on AD user.

Somehow however the result string from the console output is always empty. I can't find what's going wrong. No crashes or anything just no output.

```
public static class Process
{
    static readonly IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = (IntPtr)(-1);
    static readonly HandleRef NullHandleRef = new HandleRef(null, IntPtr.Zero);

    const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;
    public const UInt32 Infinite = 0xffffffff;
    const int STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x100;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetHandleInformation(IntPtr hObject, HANDLE_FLAGS dwMask, HANDLE_FLAGS dwFlags);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CloseHandle", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern UInt32 WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr handle, UInt32 milliseconds);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int GetConsoleOutputCP();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateNamedPipe(string name, int openMode, int pipeMode, int maxInstances, int outBufSize, int inBufSize, int timeout, IntPtr lpPipeAttributes);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFileName, int dwDesiredAccess, int dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, int dwCreationDisposition, int dwFlagsAndAttributes, HandleRef hTemplateFile);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int whichHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool GetExitCodeProcess(IntPtr process, ref UInt32 exitCode);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateProcessAsUser", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(IntPtr hToken, String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine,
                                                  ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
                                                  ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandle,
                                                  int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment,
                                                  String lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
                                                  out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx")]
    public static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, uint dwDesiredAccess,
                                               ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, int TokenType,
                                               int ImpersonationLevel, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);


    /// <summary>
    /// This is class is designed to operate inside an ASP.NET web application.
    /// The assumption is that the calling thread is operating with an impersonated security token.
    /// This class will change the imperonated security token to a primary token, and call CreateProcessAsUser.
    /// To use this function, the following security priviliges need to be set for the ASPNET account 
    /// using the local security policy MMC snap-in. CreateProcessAsUser requirement.
    /// "Replace a process level token"/SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME/SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
    /// "Adjust memory quotas for a process"/SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME/SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege
    /// </summary>
    public static bool Start(string command, string workingDirectory)
    {
        bool ret;
        try
        {

            var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            if (identity == null)
            {
                Trace.LogException("Start import conversion:  Get current identity token failed", null);
                return false;
            }

            IntPtr Token = identity.Token;

            const uint GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000;

            const int SecurityImpersonation = 2;
            const int TokenType = 1;

            var DupedToken = new IntPtr(0);

            var sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES { bInheritHandle = false };
            sa.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);
            sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = (IntPtr)0;

            ret = DuplicateTokenEx(Token, GENERIC_ALL, ref sa, SecurityImpersonation, TokenType, ref DupedToken);
            if (ret == false)
            {
                Trace.LogException(
                    "Start import conversion: DuplicateTokenEx failed with " + new Win32Exception().Message, null);
                return false;
            }


            IntPtr stdoutReadHandle;
            IntPtr stdoutWriteHandle;
            IntPtr stdinHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
            CreatePipe(out stdoutReadHandle, out stdoutWriteHandle, false);
            SetHandleInformation(stdoutReadHandle, HANDLE_FLAGS.INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAGS.INHERIT);

            var si = new STARTUPINFO();
            si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
            si.lpDesktop = "";
            si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
            si.hStdInput = stdinHandle;
            si.hStdOutput = stdoutWriteHandle;
            si.hStdError = stdoutWriteHandle;

            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
            ret = CreateProcessAsUser(DupedToken, null, command, ref sa, ref sa, true, 0, (IntPtr)0, workingDirectory,
                                      ref si, out pi);
            UInt32 exitCode = 123456;
            if (pi.hProcess != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 180000);
                GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, ref exitCode);
            }

            var lastException = new Win32Exception();

            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            CloseHandle(stdoutWriteHandle);
            CloseHandle(stdinHandle);

            var safeHandle = new SafeFileHandle(stdoutReadHandle, true);
            string result;
            try
            {
                var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(GetConsoleOutputCP());
                var reader =
                    new StreamReader(
                        new FileStream(safeHandle, FileAccess.Read, 0x1000, true),
                        encoding);

                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!safeHandle.IsClosed)
                {
                    safeHandle.Close();
                }
            }

            if (ret == false || exitCode > 0)
            {
                Trace.LogException(
                    "Start import conversion: CreateProcessAsUser failed with " + lastException.Message + " => Exitcode: " + exitCode + " => Output: " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? string.Empty : result), null);
                return false;
            }


            ret = CloseHandle(DupedToken);

            if (ret == false)
            {
                Trace.LogException("Start import conversion: Closing token failed with " + new Win32Exception().Message,
                                   null);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ret = false;
            Trace.LogFatalException(e);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private static void CreatePipe(out IntPtr parentHandle, out IntPtr childHandle, bool parentInputs)
    {
        string pipename = @"\\.\pipe\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        parentHandle = CreateNamedPipe(pipename, 0x40000003, 0, 0xff, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (parentHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        int childAcc = 0x40000000;
        if (parentInputs)
        {
            childAcc = -2147483648;
        }
        childHandle = CreateFile(pipename, childAcc, 3, IntPtr.Zero, 3, 0x40000080, NullHandleRef);
        if (childHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    enum HANDLE_FLAGS
    {
        INHERIT = 1,
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public int cb;
        public String lpReserved;
        public String lpDesktop;
        public String lpTitle;
        public uint dwX;
        public uint dwY;
        public uint dwXSize;
        public uint dwYSize;
        public uint dwXCountChars;
        public uint dwYCountChars;
        public uint dwFillAttribute;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public short wShowWindow;
        public short cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public uint dwProcessId;
        public uint dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public bool bInheritHandle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define these variables globally:

```
private const int CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;
private static IntPtr Pi_EnvBlock = default(IntPtr);
```

and call CreateProcessAsUser like that:

```
ret = CreateProcessAsUser(DupedToken, null, command, ref sa, ref sa, true, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, Pi_EnvBlock, workingDirectory, ref si, out pi);
```

Also I advise you to change your class name to different one than Process. It may cause some problems.